# Convert column from Date type to Timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a table with column named `modify` which is of type `Date`. I have converted it to type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

This column data is updated by trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigA()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
    new.modify=current_date;
    return new;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

which simply keep track of when someone updated the row.

the `current_date` was ok for `Date` but it lack time so I wanted to change it to: `current_timestamp`. However according to the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT): `current_timestamp` gives `timestamp with time zone`.

I pass on the whole page and couldn't find what gives the current date and time for `timestamp without time zone` type.

My question: How to insert the current date and time to a `timestamp without time zone` field.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LOCALTIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigA()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin
    new.modify=LOCALTIMESTAMP;
    return new;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The PostgreSQL [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) mention:

> CURRENT_TIME and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP deliver values with time zone;
>   LOCALTIME and LOCALTIMESTAMP deliver values without time zone.